# Float 2 images to the right directly under each other, without pushing text down

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

How can I float 2 images to the right and directly under each other, without pushing my text on the left down?

Comment: Please add your current HTML and CSS so that someone can help to improve your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't want to float both images, as they'll be next to each other. What you want to do is put both images in a div and float the div. Something like...

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="floated-imgs">
        <img src="img1">
        <img src="img2">
    </div>
    Text, content and whatnot.

</div>
```

CSS

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
#floated-imgs { float: right; }
#floated-imgs img {display: block; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PQChY/

Answer (score 0):

Put both imgs inside a div and float that div.

```
<div id="img">
    <img src="...">
    <img src="...">
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
```

And

```
#img {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/buA2g/